# how to loop parent and filter sibling from a single API query?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

Rookie question :).

With the following data, I'd like to loop through domains first then loop through subdomains.
I can't figure out how to pass the id (tried with computed)

```
domains: [
  {
    id: 1,
    parent_id: NULL,
    title: 'Domain 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    parent_id: NULL,
    title: 'Domain 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    parent_id: 1,
    title: 'SubDomain 11'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    parent_id: 1,
    title: 'Sub Domain 12'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    parent_id: 2,
    title: 'SubDomain 21'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    parent_id: 2,
    title: 'Sub Domain 22'
  },
]
```

And the result I'd like:

Domain 1.
Subdomain 11
Subdomain 12

Domain 2
Subdomain 21.
Subdomain 22.

Current code

```
<template>
  <div v-for="domain in rootDomains" :key="domain.id">
    <h2 class="text-2xl">{{ domain.name }}</h2>
    <div v-for="subdomain in subDomains(domain.id)" :key="subdomain.id">
      {{ subdomain.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        domains: [],
      };
    },
    [...]
    computed: {
      rootDomains() {
        return this.domains.filter(domain => domain.parent_id === null);
      },
      subDomains(parentId) {
        return this.domains.filter(domain => domain.parent_id === parentId);
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a parameter to a computed property like `property(){ return (param)=>{...}}` instead of `property(param){ return ...}` and `NULL` should be `null`

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      domains: [{
          id: 1,
          parent_id: null,
          title: 'Domain 1'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          parent_id: null,
          title: 'Domain 2'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          parent_id: 1,
          title: 'SubDomain 11'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          parent_id: 1,
          title: 'Sub Domain 12'
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          parent_id: 2,
          title: 'SubDomain 21'
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          parent_id: 2,
          title: 'Sub Domain 22'
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    rootDomains() {
      return this.domains.filter(domain => domain.parent_id === null);
    },
    subDomains() {
      return (parentId) => this.domains.filter(domain => domain.parent_id === parentId);
    },
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="domain in rootDomains" :key="domain.id">
    <h2 class="text-2xl">{{ domain.name }}</h2>
    <div v-for="subdomain in subDomains(domain.id)" :key="subdomain.id">
      {{ subdomain.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```